# What is controlling the default style of the radios and checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

Depending of the sites, I get two different default styles for the radios and checkboxes.

The images below have been taken with the same OS/browser (**MacOS Mojave**, **Chrome 72**).

## 1) The blue/white style:

For instance, in Gmail:

[image]

## 2) The grey/black style:

For instance, in Reddit:

[image]

In both styles, the elements have the CSS rule `-webkit-appearance: radio/checkbox`.

Any idea what's controlling this default style?

Comment: Form elements like checkboxes and radio buttons look different depending on the user’s browser and operating system. Although, you can apply CSS and JS to make it consistent for everyone

Comment: Oh I am able to see the same behaviour on both websites you mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser's zoom settings.

The macOS-style boxes are only shown when the zoom settings are at 100%. The Chrome / WebKit style boxes are shown at all other zoom levels.